# sdl2 key press prob on win 8.1

Tags: c++, c++11, windows-8

I've run into a prob with key press handling at least and possibly event handling in general trying to implement a message loop using SDL2.0.3 on a windows 8.1 machine while programming in c++11. I have no probs in SDL1 but now the loop isn't acting as expected.

The loops code is

```
bool        running = true;
Uint8       eventstate;
SDL_Event   event;

void msg::loop() {
    //eventstate = SDL_EventState(SDL_QUIT, SDL_ENABLE);
    //myStream << "Entering message loop" << endl;
    while(running) {
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event) > 0) {
            if(event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                running = false;
            }
            if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
            cout << event.key.keysym.sym << " pressed" << endl;
            }

            if(event.type == SDL_KEYUP) {
                cout << event.key.keysym.sym << " released" << endl;
            }
         }
    }
//myStream << "Exiting message loop" << endl;
}
```

My prob is that it doesn't appear to see the SDL_QUIT event so I can't close a window unless I use the task manager to do it. Also on entering the loop the prog prints
1 pressed

pressing and releasing any key results in
1 released
being printed

I never see notification of any keys being held down.

Also I'm using code blocks 13.12 set up as per the lazyfoo tutorial

Am I doing something wrong, is it a windows 8 quirk, or an SDL2 prob?

PS I realize you can't see it but nullptr is used instead of NULL for pointers not yet pointing at anything

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved

The above code was/is right it seems. However the setup of SDL2 requires I use

```
#include <SDL.h>
```

and one of my headers had

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
```

Once I finally noticed that and reverted to the first, all worked as expected. Something so simple and so easily missed

Sorry about the mix up guys